# Dropping rows based on date and other boolean condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe formatted like this in pandas.

```
(df)
School ID      Num          Status       Date
School 1       6000         Active       2020-07-18
School 2       9-999        InActive     2020-09-05
School 3       9-999        Active       2020-03-30
School 4       8000         Active       2020-12-14
School 5       8999         InActive     2020-10-21
School 6       8999         Active       2020-03-12
....
```

I want to delete duplicate rows based on the num column, such as how there are duplicates between School 2 and 3 along with 5 and 6. based on which had the most recent date and if the School's status is active. So in the case of 9-999, School 2's row would be deleted since it is inActive and School 3's is Active.

However, if 8999 is entered, even though School 5 has the most recent date, its status is Inactive, so it would be deleted and School 6's row would be kept.

So the result of the above conditions would be

```
(df)
School ID      Num          Status       Date
School 1       6000         Active       2020-07-18
School 3       9-999        Active       2020-03-30
School 4       8000         Active       2020-12-14
School 6       8999         Active       2020-03-12
....
```

I'm not sure if I need a conditional statement or if I can just sort by Status and Date to drop duplicates such as

```
df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates('School ID',keep='last')
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Since `'Active' < 'InActive'` we can use `drop_duplicates` with `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values('Status').drop_duplicates('Num').sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   School  ID    Num  Status        Date
0  School   1   6000  Active  2020-07-18
2  School   3  9-999  Active  2020-03-30
3  School   4   8000  Active  2020-12-14
5  School   6   8999  Active  2020-03-12
```